# How generate numbers with Uniform distribution

Tags: distribution

I need to generate numbers following uniform distribution.

Suppose I have one interval (ten minutes) and a pseudo-random number *`x`*, how can I determinate the parameter *`a,b`*?

```
ten minute = is the temporally interval
a = is the lower-bound
b = is the upper-bound
x = is pseudo random number
```

the purpose is generate numbers distributed like uniformal distribution!

Comment: Please add a bit of detail. Is the language or environment important? What are *x*, *a* and *b*? What is the significance of "ten minutes"?

Comment: What is the range of `x`?  Some PRNGs return integers, some return only positive integers, some return floats/doubles in slightly different ranges: [0,1), (0,1], or [0,1].  What are you you being given?

Answer (score 0):

Given the few facts,

```
a = is the lower-bound
b = is the upper-bound
x = is pseudo random number
```

and
a generic task to "**generate numbers distributed like uniformal distribution**"

these solutions are ready-made:

---

### NumPy

```
x = numpy.random.uniform( low = a, high = b, size = None )
```

---

### MATLAB

```
x = unifrnd( a, b );
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what to do with `x`, but here's some code that will give you `n` numbers uniformly distributed between `a` and `b`

```
import numpy as np
np.random.rand(n) * (b-a) + a
```